How should I apply FACT technique on this circuit?
I am learning the fast analytical circuit technique. How could I calculate the pole in the circuit below? I also calculated in the "traditional" way.

I was able to determine the zero and the static gain, but for the pole I would need the time constants that the capacitors "see". If s=0, an open circuit is created.



How should I determine the pole?
I also don't understand why if the circuit contains two energy storages, then the transfer function will be first order?
EDIT:
If I convert the two capacitors into one capacitor, the pole can be determined. I don't know if this is correct.


I gave an answer below but realizing that the two capacitors are in series, as you did, is perfectly valid and is a neat option : )

Oh, I'm sorry, I missed that one : ) The trick is to write the time constant with a finite-value element - albeit approaching infinity or zero - so that you can factor it or simplify final expressions. This is the easiest way I found and there is no need to insert a dummy element in the schematic: you "see" infinity, replace the symbol by \$R_{INF}\$ or \$R_s\$ if you "see" a short circuit. Here we go:

Then, you carry on with the high-frequency gains and simplify/factor the expressions:

Finally, plot magnitude and phase of the three expressions, they are identical:


Now that’s what I call customer service!! I printed the answer out and taped it inside the back cover of the book :)

Hi hi... : ) Summer break is a good time, between a mountain bike outing and a fresh beverage (of any kind ^_^) to look for unanswered questions on FACTs. The next book on loop control is gone for production already so I can relax! Cheers, Christophe
